# Variation of electromagnetic part of action

Tags: general-relativity, variational-calculus, classical-field-theory

I've got the same problem as Gabriel Luz Almeida had out here: [Variation of Maxwell action with respect to the vierbein - Einstein-Cartan Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317932/variation-of-maxwell-action-with-respect-to-the-vierbein-einstein-cartan-theor?rq=1) I try to vary the electromagnetic part of action i.e. 
$$-\frac{1}{2}F \wedge \star F$$ with the respect of vierbein. I'm trying to do it in various ways and always obtain (I will write $a$ instead of $\alpha$ etc.)
$$\frac{1}{2}f^a \wedge \left[(i_a F)\wedge \star F+F \wedge i_a \star F\right].$$ It's the same result as the one Gabriel obtained since 
$$F_{cb}f^c \wedge e^b = \frac{1}{2}F_{cb}f^c \wedge e^b+\frac{1}{2}F_{cb}f^c \wedge e^b =\frac{1}{2}(F_{cb}f^c \wedge e^b-F_{bc}f^c \wedge e^b )=\frac{1}{2}(F_{bc}f^b \wedge e^c -F_{bc}f^c \wedge e^b)=\frac{1}{2}F_{bc}(f^b \wedge e^c - f^c \wedge e^b)=\frac{1}{2}F_{bc}f^s \wedge (\delta ^b _{\ s}e^c - \delta ^c _{\ s}e^b)=\frac{1}{2}F_{bc}f^s \wedge i_{e_s}(e^b \wedge e^c)=f^s \wedge i_{e_s}F,$$ where $i$ denotes the interior product. Similarly with $\frac{1}{2}F^{ab}\epsilon _{abcd}f^c \wedge e^d$. I varied it several times for example in the following way 
$$\delta (F \wedge \star F)=\delta F \wedge \star F+F \wedge \delta \star F=\delta (\frac{1}{2}F_{ab}e^a \wedge e^b)\wedge \star F+F \wedge \delta (\star \frac{1}{2}F_{cd}e^c \wedge e^d)=\frac{1}{2}F_{ab}(\delta e^a \wedge e^b+e^a \wedge \delta e^b)\wedge \star F+F \wedge \delta (\frac{1}{2}F_{cd}\eta ^{ce}\eta^{df}e^ i \wedge e^j\epsilon_{efij}\frac{1}{2!})=\delta e^s \wedge \frac{1}{2}F_{ab}i_{e_s}e^a \wedge e^b\wedge \star F+F\wedge \frac{1}{2}F_{cd}\eta^{ce}\eta^{df}(\delta e^i \wedge e^j+e^i \wedge \delta e^j)\epsilon_{efij}\frac{1}{2!}=\delta e^s \wedge i_{e_s}F\wedge \star F+F \wedge \delta e^s \wedge i_{e_s}\star F=\delta e^s \wedge (i_{e_s}F \wedge \star F+F\wedge i_{e_s}\star F)$$
(I've got $\delta e^s \equiv f^s $). Instead Walter Thiring in his Classical field theory gives 
$$\delta e^s \wedge (i_{e_s}F \wedge \star F-F\wedge i_{e_s}\star F)$$
Someone responded to Gabriel. In particualar he wrote that under transformation $$e^a \mapsto e^a+ f^a$$ $e_a$ obeys the transformation law $$e_a \mapsto e_a- f_a$$ because $$\eta^{ab}f_a=-f^b.$$ I cannot agree. Since $f_a$ can be defined $$f_a:=g_{ac}f^c$$ we've got $$g^{ab}f_a =g_{ac}g^{ab}f^c =\delta ^b _{\ c}f^c=f^b.$$ 
Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? How to obtain $$\delta e^s \wedge (i_{e_s}F \wedge \star F-F\wedge i_{e_s}\star F)?$$